# Wordpress Theme Problem

Tags: themes

Can anyone tell me, why this theme is not working? 
My Configuration : 
XAMMP 1.8.1
PHP 5.4.7
Wordpress 3.5.1
After Installing the theme with other necessary plugins and frameworks, I activated the theme. But it notifies me with e message " Your theme does not support Open Theme Framework "

http://www.web2feel.com/zenshop/

Comment: There is only [**one** match](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Open+Theme+Framework%22) for that framework: your question. So, I am afraid nobody can tell you what’s going on here. Disable all plugins – does it still happen? Also, I cannot see that message on the page you are linking to.

Comment: I gave the download link of the theme. When I activate it, it displays bunch of php codes

Comment: Please add [debug information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) to your **question** to make answers possible. Also try it without any plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You should also consider installing the [Theme Check Plug-in](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/theme-check/)

The theme has several issues, some of them aren't crucial errors but the list is filled with too many deprecated functions to use the theme (In my opinion).

I installed the theme w/out the plugin's it recommends, which is probably the actual source of you specific error. I would consider choosing another theme and save some time.

Here's the output of the [theme-check plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/theme-check/):

**[The Output](http://snipplr.com/view/69874/zenshop-wordpress-theme-error-output/)**